# Retornar View usando View Data ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

sou iniciante em ASP Net e estou em fase de "estudos", queria saber porque meu código está dando erros de atributos. Estou usando um método POST para mandar os atributos para uma VIEW. Segue em anexo imagem do problema.

View da minha HOME:

```
@model PostGetModel.Models.Pessoa
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<form action="/Home/Lista" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Pessoa</legend>
        <div>
            <label for="PessoaId">Código da pessoa</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="number" value="3" id="IdPessoa" name="PessoaId"/>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="Nome">Nome da pessoa</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@Model.Nome" id="Nome" name="Nome" />
        </div>


        <div>
            <label for="Twitter">Twitter da pessoa</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" value="@Model.Twitter" id="Twitter" name="Twitter" />
        </div>

        <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JPG do meu problema.

[image: Problema, Controller, View e Solução em execução]

Essa é minha primeira pergunta no Stack OverFlow, estou grato por fazer parte dessa comunidade e se alguém puder me ajudar. Mil desculpas se não expliquei direito. Qualquer coisa dou um EDIT.

Comment: Bem vindo Breno. Algumas melhorias que pode fazer na pergunta: coloque a mensagem do erro e não a imagem, coloque o fonte da controller e não a imagem. Prefira sempre texto, quando este for possível.

Comment: Breno assim que fizer as correções que o George mencionou podemos ajudar. Estou aguardando e te ajudo.

Comment: Por favor não use imagens para mostrar códigos, leia https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3635, então após isto o que for mensagem de erro e código transforme em texto e edite sua pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Uma maneira mais interessante, seria você passar os dados para o model e recupera-lo na View.
Exemplo:

1. Preencha sua lista, ou seus dados no model;
2. Depois, retorne os valores para dentro da View, `return View(obj);`;
3. Na view, referencie o `@model` para o modelo de dados criado no controlador;
4. Nos componentes, utilize o Razor, como por exemplo um TextBox
   `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.propriedade`.

Conheça mais sobre [Razor](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/razor_syntax.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Ocorreu esse erro pois o campo IdPessoa está nulo.

Para resolver esse problema:

1) Realizar um bind da Model com o campo IdPessoa:

```
     <input type="number" value="3" value="@Model.IdPessoa" id="IdPessoa" name="PessoaId"/>
```

2) Eu alteraria no Action Lista para receber a como parâmetro a Model:

```
     public ActionResult Lista(Pessoa model)
```

Answer (score 0):

O Name da tag input deve ser igual ao parâmetro no Controller.

Aqui está "PessoaId"

`<input type="number" value="3" id="IdPessoa" name="PessoaId"/>`

E no Controller está "idPessoa".